# "If I would have given you my snail address, could you send me some reprints."

Tags: conditional-constructions

What is the difference between

> If I would have given you my snail address, could you send me some reprints.

and

> If I would give you my snail address, could you send me some reprints.

In particular, are **both** grammatically correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, neither is correct

The simplest way to phrase this idea would be:

> If I give you my snail address, could you send me some reprints.

Another possible form would be:

> If I gave you my snail address, could you send me some reprints.

The use of "gave" makes this more hypothetical, but in this case the meaning is almost identical.  If the intention is to discuss a possible past event that did not happen, one could say or write:

> If I had given you my snail address, could you have sent me some reprints.

This means that I did not give you the address, but I now want to know what might have happened if I had done so.

By the way, while postal mail is often called "snail mail", it is not yet usual to refer to a postal address as a "snail address". It is a "postal address" or a "mailing address", or perhaps a "physical address".

Answer (score 0):

The first example has incorrect sequence of tenses.

The second expression is not idiomatic.

The correct expression is

> If I give you my address, would/could you send me some reprints.